# Capacitor support for DC power supply

Tags: capacitor

I have a simple circuit shown in the diagram; the capacitor shown in red across the power supply terminals is not in the circuit at this time.
[image]
The momentary toggle sw at the top connects to both, either the set of the reset coil of a latching relay as well as a solenoid in the model railroad switch (turnout).  The turnouts require a momentary pulse to switch and I am using the latching relay to drive either of two LEDs to indicate the turnout direction.

Now, the problem is that the turnouts switch without fail, but the latching relay does not always flop.  I'm wondering if the turnout solenoid is drawing too much current for the DC supply to keep its voltage up and thus denying the latching relay the opportunity to react.

My question is:  Would the addition of the capacitor help?

Comment: If you disconnect the solenoids from the circuit, are you then able to set / reset the latching relay?  Also any data sheets on the solenoid specs or the latching relay and power supply would be helpful. Also what is the distance between the power supply and there the solenoids/relay are?  If its a long distance then a cap might help

Comment: Your design lacks details on V, I max, L,DCR for all, PSU peak current is too small.Do you have a battery and trickle charger instead.

Comment: Hi GCR and Tony, thank you for the response.  The relays do seem to work properly on  my benchboard without the solenoids connected.  The power supply is actually a spare train control unit which give between 7 and 18 v DC; I adjust it to between 12 and 13 v.  I don't have any specs on the solenoids and for the latching relay I only know that it takes "12vDC" and requires 50 ms of 12 v to set or reset.  The solenoids are between 10 and 75 cable feet away from the toggle switch.  The relays are within one foot of the toggle switch.

Comment: Tony, I have not tried the battery with trickle charger yet.  All voltages are 12 v DC for the solenoids & the latching relay coils.   I don't have specs on the solenoids; I'm just going on the supposition that the solenoids drag the PS voltage down to o low for the LRs & that the cap will provide enough buffer to compensate for the pull-down.  One other piece of info is that the latching relay sometimes does flip, just not reliably.  If you don't think the cap will help, I'll get a battery.  I am just hoping to make the spare train controller work as the power supply :)